# WordNet similarities java

Tags: java, perl, wordnet

I have found a kool library in Perl http://www.d.umn.edu/~tpederse/similarity.html
which perform a lot of similarities between words, there is something like this in java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Java WordNet::Similarity](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/Users/drh21/) (you have to scroll down a bit for the downloads).

According to [the WordNet project page](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#Java)

```
Java WordNet::Similarity [...] is a pure Java version of Perl WordNet::Similarity
(developed by Ted Pedersen). The code supports all of the measures found in the
Perl version.
```